# Tamil Phonetic Keyboard Input not showing in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, fonts

Recently Installed Ubuntu 22.04 development Version, but Tamil (Phonetic) Keyboard input not showing, how to rectify this problem.

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Note: It's still in *alpha* with *beta-freeze* scheduled for 28-March, and *beta* release scheduled for 31-March-2022

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `ta_IN` locale has been generated on your system, and if so the Tamil input sources are shown in a *Tamil* sub menu, i.e. you should click *Tamil* and not proceed to *Other*.

Also, the `ibus-m17n` package needs to be installed.

***As others have pointed out the question is off topic, but 22.04 is not different in this respect than the currently supported releases.***

Comment: How to generate ta_IN ? 

ibus-m17n is already the newest version, but tamil phonetic not showing

Comment: @AnandhaRaja: I didn't mean to say that you need to generate it. I just guessed that it had already been generated since you didn't find any Tamil input sources in the "Other" view. If you want you can check by running the command `locale -a`